# Trying to parallelise minimax for tic tac toe, python

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I'm trying to parallelise a pretty simple minimax implementation for tic tac toe in python. It's for a reinforcement learning thing but honestly I'm so stuck with this. I haven't done much with parallel computing besides Golang and Golang definitely makes it pretty simple.

Sorry I just don't even know where to start. I'm asking way too much here, but. I've found things about OpenMP, but that's hard to understand too.

Can anyone point me in some direction?

```
def compMove(board):
  bestScore = -1000
  bestMove = 0

  for index, x in enumerate(board):
    
    if(x == 0):
      board[index] = 2
      score = minimax(board, 0, False)
      board[index] = 0
      if(score > bestScore):
        bestScore = score
        bestMove = index
  return bestMove

def checkDraw(board):
  for index, x in enumerate(board):
    if(x == 0):
      return False
  return True
  


def checkWhoWon(board, mark):
  if(board[0]==board[1] and board[1]==board[2] and board[2]== mark):
    return True
  elif(board[3]==board[4] and board[4]==board[5] and board[5]== mark):
    return True
  elif(board[6]==board[7] and board[7]==board[8] and board[8]== mark):
    return True
  elif(board[0]==board[3] and board[3]==board[6] and board[6]== mark):
    return True
  elif(board[1]==board[4] and board[4]==board[7] and board[7]== mark):
    return True
  elif(board[2]==board[5] and board[5]==board[8] and board[8]== mark):
    return True
  elif(board[0]==board[4] and board[4]==board[8] and board[8]== mark):
    return True
  elif(board[6]==board[4] and board[4]==board[2] and board[2]== mark):
    return True
  else: return False


def minimax(board, depth, isMaximising):
  if checkWhoWon(board, 2):
    return 100
    
  elif checkWhoWon(board, 1):
    return -100
  elif checkDraw(board):
    return 10000
  if isMaximising:
    bestScore = -1000

    for index, x in enumerate(board):
      if(x == 0):
        board[index] = 2
        score = minimax(board, 0, False)
        board[index] = 0
        if(score > bestScore):
          bestScore = score
    return bestScore
  else:
    bestScore = 1000

    for index, x in enumerate(board):
      if(x == 0):
        board[index] = 1
        score = minimax(board, 0, True)
        board[index] = 0
        if(score < bestScore):
          bestScore = score
    return bestScore
```

Comment: The CPython interpreter is very slow and should be at least 20-200 times slower than a C/C++ code for this in sequential. This it is much more efficient to use a right too rather than using more computing resources. Rewriting your code in C/C++ can be cumbersome though. You can use Cython or Numba to compile your Python code to a native one. This is often not as fast as a C/C++ code but close to. Cython and Numba provide basic parallel loops. This is far from being as flexible as OpenMP but this should be enough for your needs here. By the way you need to use Numpy first.